# Center Label inside a Card Component

Tags: reactjs

[Look at This Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fFdFp.png)
[Something Like This](https://i.stack.imgur.com/X5r20.png)
I am using Ant Design Template. I am Using a Card Component. Inside a Card I have a label. I want to show that label in the center of the Card how can I achieve this
 Here is my Code

```
<Card style={{ height: 300, alignItems:Center, backgroundColor:'#344A54', justifyContent:'Center', alignItems:'Center'}} >
  <Input placeholder="Enter site name" style={{backgroundColor:'#344A54', border:0, marginTop:-100, marginLeft:-30}} />
  <Popover content={titlecontent} title="Title" trigger="hover">
    <label style={{fontSize:50,flex:5,alignSelf:'Center',textAlign:'center'}} contentEditable>
      Your page title
    </label>
  </Popover>
</Card>
<Card style={{ height: 300 ,alignContent:CurryRight}}>
</Card>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`alignItems: 'center'` and `justifyContent: 'center'` only work with flexbox. So try add `display: 'flex'` to card's style.